# RuntimeException when running rebuildData.php

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I upgraded my MW from 1.31 to 1.33 and SMW from 2.5.6 to 3.1 by following the [official tutorials](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Upgrade/Upgrade_from_SMW_2.5_or_later_and_MW_1.25_or_later). Everything works fine until `Step 6` when I run `rebuildData.php` to rebuild the data and it throws an exception after about 10000 updates. Here is the exception message:

```
... updating 10281     [S: User:Reddgamer]
[d55bfb09d717f88aa3e7da6e] [no req]   RuntimeException from line 58 of /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/SQLStore/Lookup/SingleEntityQueryLookup.php: Expected a ValueDescription instance!
Backtrace:
#0 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/includes/query/SMW_QueryProcessor.php(338): SMW\SQLStore\Lookup\SingleEntityQueryLookup->getQueryResult(SMWQuery)
#1 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/ParserFunctions/AskParserFunction.php(364): SMWQueryProcessor::getResultFromQuery(SMWQuery, array, integer, integer)
#2 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/ParserFunctions/AskParserFunction.php(197): SMW\ParserFunctions\AskParserFunction->doFetchResultsFromFunctionParameters(array, array)
#3 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/ParserFunctions/ShowParserFunction.php(45): SMW\ParserFunctions\AskParserFunction->parse(array)
#4 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/ParserFunctionFactory.php(428): SMW\ParserFunctions\ShowParserFunction->parse(array)
#5 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(3528): SMW\ParserFunctionFactory->SMW\{closure}(Parser, string, string)
#6 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(3235): Parser->callParserFunction(PPFrame_DOM, string, array)
#7 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Preprocessor_DOM.php(1285): Parser->braceSubstitution(array, PPFrame_DOM)
#8 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(3152): PPFrame_DOM->expand(DOMElement)
#9 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Preprocessor_DOM.php(1285): Parser->braceSubstitution(array, PPFrame_DOM)
#10 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(3049): PPFrame_DOM->expand(DOMElement, integer)
#11 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(1359): Parser->replaceVariables(string)
#12 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(491): Parser->internalParse(string)
#13 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/content/WikitextContent.php(369): Parser->parse(string, Title, ParserOptions, boolean, boolean, integer)
#14 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/includes/content/AbstractContent.php(555): WikitextContent->fillParserOutput(Title, integer, ParserOptions, boolean, ParserOutput)
#15 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/includes/ContentParser.php(186): AbstractContent->getParserOutput(Title, integer, ParserOptions, boolean)
#16 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/includes/ContentParser.php(145): SMW\ContentParser->fetchFromContent()
#17 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/MediaWiki/Jobs/UpdateJob.php(197): SMW\ContentParser->parse()
#18 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/MediaWiki/Jobs/UpdateJob.php(137): SMW\MediaWiki\Jobs\UpdateJob->parse_content()
#19 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/MediaWiki/Jobs/UpdateJob.php(94): SMW\MediaWiki\Jobs\UpdateJob->doUpdate()
#20 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/SQLStore/Rebuilder/Rebuilder.php(237): SMW\MediaWiki\Jobs\UpdateJob->run()
#21 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/Maintenance/DataRebuilder.php(423): SMW\SQLStore\Rebuilder\Rebuilder->rebuild(integer)
#22 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/Maintenance/DataRebuilder.php(349): SMW\Maintenance\DataRebuilder->do_update(integer)
#23 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/Maintenance/DataRebuilder.php(200): SMW\Maintenance\DataRebuilder->rebuild_all()
#24 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/maintenance/rebuildData.php(202): SMW\Maintenance\DataRebuilder->rebuild()
#25 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/maintenance/doMaintenance.php(96): SMW\Maintenance\RebuildData->execute()
#26 /home/example/public_html/dev.example.com/wiki/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/maintenance/rebuildData.php(261): require_once(string)
#27 {main
```

Does someone know why this is happening and how I could get it sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

I created the bug report for you: [smw issue 4349](https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/issues/4349)

Comment: Thanks for doing that mate!

Comment: It may take longer to get this fixed. In the meantime have a look at either the `--ignore-exceptions` or `--force-update` flags to the maintenance script.